# AXUIElement memory management

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I wrote like this:

```
AXUIElementRef windowUIElement = AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid);
.....
if (windowUIElement) {
   CFRelease(windowUIElement);
   windowUIElement = NULL;
}
```

but when I using instrument Leak, it [image]

Then I change the code to

```
AXUIElementRef windowUIElement = CFRetain(AXUIElementCreateApplication(pid));
.....
if (windowUIElement) {
   CFRelease(windowUIElement);
   windowUIElement = NULL;
}
```

But still:
[image]

Really don't know why, I have googled a lot, find some similar questions but no answers, hope some one can help.

Comment: `CFRetain` retains an object and can create another leak, it certainly doesn't fix it. Do you call `AXUIElementCreateApplication` twice?

Comment: @Willeke thanks, I guess CFRetain is not the right answer, but I have no other solutions. I only call AXUIElementCreateApplication once and assign it to windowUIElement and then CFRelease it.